# Problem with the DevExpress XtraGridView control

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I have one `xtragrid control on my devxpress form` .  I've created the `columns of my grid at runtime when i load the form` . I'm developing the Field chooser for my grid view which is situated on the same form. For that i used the `repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit`control & in that control i added the column names which will be present in the xtragrid.

Basically i created the columns to the xtragrid with the Visible property to false. When user checks particular column name by using repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit  then i set the Visible to true & again if user unchecked the column name then again i set the visible to false. & while creating column i set the width of the column.

`Problem which i'm facing is that if user select the all fields from the repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit  then the grid control should show the horizontal scroll bar automatically when require.`

`And another problem is that with the columns is besides setting the width of the column, it is not showing the required width of that column . it shrinks that all column width .`

code which i use for creating column to the xtragridview at run time is as follows -

```
 public void AddGridColumn(string fieldName, string caption, int nRowWidth, RepositoryItem Item, object oCollection, string DisplayMember, string ValueMember, string format, FormatType type)
        {
            DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn column = ColumnView.Columns.AddField(fieldName);
            column.Caption = caption;
            column.ColumnEdit = Item;
            column.DisplayFormat.FormatType = type;
            column.DisplayFormat.FormatString = format;
            column.VisibleIndex =  ColumnView.VisibleColumns.Count;
            column.Width = nRowWidth;
        }
```

code for the `field chooser` is as follows - 
I used this function for filling the items of the repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit  control

```
private void FieldCollection()
    {
        allFields = new ArrayList();
        columnNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        allFields.Clear();
        repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < gvBase.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            allFields.Add(gvBase.Columns[i].Caption );
            if (gvBase.Columns[i].FieldName != "ContactID")
            {
                if (gvBase.Columns[i].Visible == true)
                {
                    if (gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label1" && gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label2" && gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label3" && gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label4" && gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label5")
                        repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit1.Items.Add(gvBase.Columns[i].Caption, CheckState.Checked);
                    if (!columnNames.ContainsKey(gvBase.Columns[i].Caption))
                        columnNames.Add(gvBase.Columns[i].Caption, gvBase.Columns[i].FieldName);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label1" && gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label2" && gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label3" && gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label4" && gvBase.Columns[i].Caption != "Label5")

                        repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit1.Items.Add(gvBase.Columns[i].Caption, CheckState.Unchecked);
                    if (!columnNames.ContainsKey(gvBase.Columns[i].FieldName))
                        columnNames.Add(gvBase.Columns[i].Caption, gvBase.Columns[i].FieldName);

                }
            }
        }
        cmbFieldChooser.EditValue = "";
    }
```

this is used for the repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit control event -

```
private void cmbFieldChooser_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
            temp.AddRange(allFields);

            string[] strFields = cmbFieldChooser.EditValue.ToString().Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < strFields.Length; i++)
            {
                if (temp.Contains(strFields[i].Trim()))
                    temp.Remove(strFields[i].Trim());
                if (strFields[i] != "")
                {
                    if (columnNames.ContainsKey(strFields[i].Trim()))
                    {
                        if (gvBase.Columns[columnNames[strFields[i].Trim()]].Visible == false)
                        {
                            gvBase.Columns[columnNames[strFields[i].Trim()]].Visible = true;
                            gvBase.Columns[columnNames[strFields[i].Trim()]].BestFit();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (temp.Count < 20)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < temp.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (columnNames.ContainsKey(temp[j].ToString().Trim()))
                    {
                        gvBase.Columns[columnNames[temp[j].ToString().Trim()]].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            cmbFieldChooser.EditValue = repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit1.GetCheckedItems();
            if ((cmbFieldChooser.EditValue.ToString()).Split(',').Length > 5)
            {
                gvBase.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false;
                gvBase.BestFitColumns();
                gvBase.HorzScrollVisibility = ScrollVisibility.Always;
            }
            else
            {
                gvBase.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = true;
                gvBase.HorzScrollVisibility = ScrollVisibility.Never;
            }

        }
```

How to resolve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: @ Priyanka : Probably you can find a solution if you search or post this question in devExpress forum http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/

Answer (score 0):

How many columns do you have in your Grid?

I see you have code there to turn off the ColumnAutoWidth once you go past 5 columns (ie 6 columns or more). Have you debugged this condition to ensure the ColumnAutoWidth is indeed being turned off?

As per [BestFitColumns Help Doc](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_BestFitColumnstopic) the BestFitColumns will only calculate for the first n rows as per the BestFitMaxRowCount property unless it it set to -1, could this be a cause?

The other thing that seems a little odd if that you are setting the EditValue of cmdFieldChooser within the cmdFieldChooser_EditValueChanged event... why so?